# JDBC and oracle database timezone handling

Tags: java, oracle, datetime, jdbc

I have created sample table in oracle DB as below

```
"CREATED_ON" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"CREATED_ON_TIMEZONE" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
"TIMEZONE_GMT" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

and inserted values from java as below

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()) ,Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

JVM timezone in ASIA/CALCUTTA. I have used SQL developer to query data.
I just wanted to clear my understanding

1. The first column stored value as per local JVM  without timezone since dataType is only timestamp i.e **29-NOV-17 07.04.28.014000000 PM**. so for column with timstamp datatype DB stores value as of local JVM which is passed by JDBC driver and there is no conversion happening either JDBC side or DB side ?
2. Second column store value with TIMEZONE i.e **29-NOV-17 07.04.28.014000000 PM 
   ASIA/CALCUTTA**. So does it mean DB stores value for column with timezone information provided by JDBC driver and there is no convrsion at DB side?
3. I want to store value in GMT so I set third parameter as GMT , it store value in GMT but timezone was still showing as of local JVM . i.e **29-NOV-17 01.34.28.014000000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA**

I was refering below article but my observations looks totally diffrent.
http://brian.pontarelli.com/2011/08/16/database-handling-for-timezones/

Comment: Are these all different values? If not, i.e. if they represent the same time I would propose a virtual column as `TIMEZONE_GMT TIMESTAMP(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CREATED_ON_TIMEZONE) ) VIRTUAL` resp. `CREATED_ON TIMESTAMP(6) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CAST(CREATED_ON_TIMEZONE AS TIMESTAMP(6)) ) VIRTUAL`

Comment: Updated question . These are same values. The main issue is with third column , it shows correct GMT value but timezone is different . It should be GMT.

Comment: You need to pass instances of `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ` through `setObject()` if you want to preserve the time zone.

Comment: Can’t you use Java 8 and `java.time`? If you can, skip the outdated `Timestamp` class. I believe you should save `LocalDateTime` objects into your timestamp column and `Instant` objects into your timestamp with timezone columns. In both cases use `PreparedStatement.setObject()`. `java.time` is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is Java `Timestamp` does not contain any time zone information.

So you insert a `TIMESTAMP` value into a column of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In such case Oracle makes an implicit cast with [FROM_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions077.htm#SQLRF00644):

```
FROM_TZ(<your value>, SESSIONTIMEZONE)
```

Command `preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()) ,Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));` would be correct only after an `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'UTC';`